# Subquery alias not showing

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, subquery

I need to find the amount of user for two categories which presents itself in an output with two columns called "basic user" and "advanced user" which get counted from the user ID's who have a specific role. A basic or advanced user is comprised of several of these roles. e.j "basic user" has roles: "Member" and "TimeTrackingWritingMember" etc.

Now the query works fine and counts and sums exactly what I need (not the prettiest) but for some reason it is not taking the "Alias" of the SUM() I've nested and I don't really understand the logic of it because it runs the whole query but it shows the column name not as "basic user" but rather as "COLUMN1" ?

```
SELECT SUM(A.ROLECOUNT) as 'Advanced User' , (SELECT SUM(A.ROLECOUNT) as 'Basic User' <---Alias
    FROM(
        SELECT roles.Name AS Role_Name,
        COUNT(DISTINCT ur.UserId ) AS RoleCount 
        FROM dbo.AbpUsers as users 
        LEFT JOIN resourcing.CompanyorganizationUnitUserRole AS ur 
        on users.Id = ur.UserId
        LEFT JOIN dbo.AbpRoles AS roles ON roles.Id = ur.RoleId
        GROUP BY roles.Name
        ) A 
    WHERE A.ROLE_NAME IN ('TimeTrackingWritingMember', 'Member'))
    FROM(
        SELECT roles.Name AS Role_Name,
        COUNT(DISTINCT ur.UserId ) AS RoleCount 
        FROM dbo.AbpUsers as users 
        LEFT JOIN resourcing.CompanyorganizationUnitUserRole AS ur 
        on users.Id = ur.UserId
        LEFT JOIN dbo.AbpRoles AS roles ON roles.Id = ur.RoleId
        GROUP BY roles.Name
        ) A
    WHERE A.ROLE_NAME IN ('OrganizationUnitLeader', 'DepartmentalCoordinator', 'OrganizationUnitSecondLeader','ResourceCoordinator');
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Advanced User|COLUMN1 <---- should be basic user
1298         |22183
```

Any help is more than appreciated!

Comment: you should move `as 'Basic User'` after parenthesis here `WHERE A.ROLE_NAME IN ('TimeTrackingWritingMember', 'Member'))`

Comment: Thanks , that solved the issue. But is this needed because it is nested in another one ?